# Rails split text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

Please help me to split a string to put into an array.

String:

```
<p>TEXT1</p>
<p><img src="img1.jpg"></p>
<p>TEXT 2</p>
<p><img src="img2.jpg"></p>
<p>TEXT3</p>
```

I need split it by

```
<p><img src="*****"></p>
```

In result array:

```
result[0]:

<p>TEXT1</p>
<p><img src="img1.jpg"></p>

result[1]

<p>TEXT 2</p>
<p><img src="img2.jpg"></p>

result[2]

<p>TEXT3</p>
```

UPD:

```
:001> str = '<p>TEXT 1</p><p><img src="/upload/posts/13/009781884.jpg"></p><p>TEXT 2</p><p><img src="/upload/posts/14/010098317.jpg"></p><p>TEXT3</p>'
:002> array = str.scan(/<p>[a-zA-Z 0-9<\/>]*<img src="[\/a-zA-Z0-9.]*"><\/p>|<p>[a-zA-Z 0-9\d\D]*<\/p>/)
 => ["<p>TEXT 1</p><p><img src=\"/upload/posts/13/009781884.jpg\"></p>", "<p>TEXT 2</p><p><img src=\"/upload/posts/14/010098317.jpg\"></p>", "<p>TEXT3</p>"]
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I try regex match, but I have a problem with a regular expression,I can not make the right.

Comment: What would I suggest is to use [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials), so you could: 1). find all `p` tags 2). go through all of them with `each` 3). push strings into `temp` until tag `p` does have `img` tag as a child tag 4). push `temp` into `result` 5). loop

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

`split(/(.*?<p><img src=".*?"><\/p>)\n/m).delete_if(&:blank?)`

the `?`s limit the matching to the minimum length and the `m` at the end of the regex make it a multiline match.  There are blank results, so we delete them w/ the `delete_if(&:blank?)`